# Convert vector back to a grid in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

In Matlab I a have 5-D grid X. I can use

```
Xsind=find(X>a)
```

to obtain the index values of X above scalar `a`. However, this gives the indices in vector form. Is there a quick way to convert this back to a grid indices giving the position in each dimension? I can do the conversion using the floor function 4 times but there must be an easier and faster way.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution:

```
[i,j,k,l,m]=ind2sub([n1,n2,n3,n4,n5],Xsind)
```

where n1,n2,n3,n4,n5 are the lengths of the 5 dimensions.